# Retrieve data using select query with null Foreign key value

Tags: sql, select, foreign-keys, inner-join

I have a 2 tables with name Vendor and VendorType . Structure are given

```
CREATE TABLE XCodesSCMERP.dbo.Vendor (
  VendorID INT IDENTITY,
  VendorTypeID INT NULL,
  VendorName VARCHAR(200) NULL,
  VendorCompany VARCHAR(200) NULL,
  FirstName VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  LastName VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  Contact VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  Phone VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  AltContact VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  Email VARCHAR(50) NULL,
  AddressBilledFrom VARCHAR(50) NULL,
  AddressShippedFrom VARCHAR(50) NULL,
  VendorNotes VARCHAR(500) NULL,
  OpeningBalance VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  OpeningDate VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  VendorAccountNo VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  CONSTRAINT PK_Vendor PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (VendorID),
  CONSTRAINT FK_Vendor_VendorTypeTable_VendorTypeID FOREIGN KEY (VendorTypeID) REFERENCES dbo.VendorTypeTable (VendorTypeID)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO




CREATE TABLE XCodesSCMERP.dbo.VendorTypeTable (
  VendorTypeID INT IDENTITY,
  VendorType VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  VendorDesc VARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
  CONSTRAINT PK_VendorTypeTable PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (VendorTypeID)
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

It is clear from structures of table that VendorTypeID is foreign key in Vendor table. Now when i want to retrieve data from Vendor table including field VendorType from VendorTypeTable than i have to use Inner Join that works fine.
But here is problem . it does' not show that records which don't have any vendorType i.e VendorTypeID is not selected . It is said to be null.
Now here is my question , how i can retrieve those records also that don't have any Vendor Type.
Would be pleasure for me , helping me in my Problem.

Note:

```
SELECT VendorID,VendorName,FirstName,LastName,VendorCompany,Contact,Phone,AltContact,Email,OpeningBalance,OpeningDate,VendorAccountNo ,VendorNotes FROM Vendor WHERE VendorTypeID='';
```

This query does not return any record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you just want `IS NULL`:

```
SELECT v.*
FROM Vendor v
WHERE VendorTypeID IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your query to something like this

> SELECT
> VendorID,VendorName,FirstName,LastName,VendorCompany,Contact,Phone,AltContact,Email,OpeningBalance,OpeningDate,VendorAccountNo
> ,VendorNotes FROM Vendor WHERE VendorTypeID IS NULL;

Note: A NULL value is different from a zero value or a field that contains spaces. A field with a NULL value is a blank field